# Как в input вставить данные value, как у <select>?

Tags: javascript, twitter, autocomplete

Хочу уйти `<select>` и перейти на `input` autocomplete.

на данный момент у меня стоит в форме поиска.

```
<select  data-placeholder="Выберите город" name="search[city]" >
     <option value="">Выберите город</option>
     <option value="tokio">Токио</option>
    </select>
```

как мне вставить значение `value="tokio"` в `input`
 названия городов передаются!

```
 var states = ['Киев', 'Москва', 'Токио'];
```

а нужно, например

```
var states = ['kiev', 'moscow', 'tokio'];
```

что бы подставлялось в `<input value="tokio"`

скрипт приведенный https://jsfiddle.net/mbaoe66f/

я использовал https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js

Comment: autocomplete не имеет ключа, используйте для этих целей select2 https://github.com/select2/select2

Comment: @tcpack4 да ну..видел у других работает как то ж.